# Can not find schema.xml file for solrcloud

Tags: schema, solrcloud, solr5

I want to change schema.xml file, but i can not find it. How to change schema.xml file?
link image : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxOsysEbbmMOQ0hoV19KaVo0SUU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

As per the image, you are working with the SolrCloud example Collection gettingstarted.

In SolrCloud schema.xml file is maintained by ZooKeeper and so when you change the schema, you will have to upload to ZooKeeper to make it effective.

Please describe in detail what you are looking for?

Note: I still don't have the privilege of comments, or else this should be in comments.